# Pagination- Scroll to Top

Tags: javascript

I'm currently utilizing pagination with the following code. I'm searching for a way to make the page scroll to the beginning of the list of content on page switch. [Example of page here.](http://sneakerwire.net/news.html) Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

```
(function($){

   $.fn.customPaginate = function(options)
   {
       var paginationContainer = this;
       var itemsToPaginate;


       var defaults = {

            itemsPerPage : 4

       };

       var settings = {};

       $.extend(settings, defaults, options);

       var itemsPerPage = settings.itemsPerPage;

       itemsToPaginate = $(settings.itemsToPaginate);
       var numberOfPaginationLinks = Math.ceil((itemsToPaginate.length / itemsPerPage));

       $("<ul></ul>").prependTo(paginationContainer);

       for(var index = 0; index < numberOfPaginationLinks; index++)
       {
            paginationContainer.find("ul").append("<li>"+ (index+1) + "</li>");
       }

       itemsToPaginate.filter(":gt(" + (itemsPerPage - 1)  + ")").hide();

       paginationContainer.find("ul li").on('click', function(){

           var linkNumber = $(this).text();

            var itemsToHide = itemsToPaginate.filter(":lt(" + ((linkNumber-1) * itemsPerPage)  + ")");
            $.merge(itemsToHide, itemsToPaginate.filter(":gt(" + ((linkNumber * itemsPerPage) - 1)  + ")"));
            itemsToHide.hide();

            var itemsToShow = itemsToPaginate.not(itemsToHide);
            itemsToShow.show();
       });

   }

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use when paginate button is clicked

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
```